# Creating Scala Project on Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

When I am creating Scala Project after installing the plugin it is not opening any project directory. Whenever I hit finish it just say "Scanning file index" and give blue square back to name of Project.
[image]

After that I tried opening the project folder on Intellij and it was created but with no sbt files and library avail . How can I properly create Scala project on Intellij.
[image]

Comment: When creating new project, is it giving you the option to select a Scala template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the [current IntelliJ IDEA release version](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html) will help.